# Looking for smallest number in this array (would like to understand the logic to solve myself; don't want the answer)

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have an array (simple array) :

```
int [] array =  { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

And a nested for-loop to find the smallest element.

```
public static int smallest(int[] array){
    int answer = 0;
        
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0 + i; j < array.length; j++){
            if(array[i] < array[j]){
                answer = i ;
            }
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

In this instance, my nested for-loop finds that the first run-through
meets my condition in which [i] is less than all the [j] elements. However,
my loop continues running, and this is where I'm getting confused with the logic/workflow.
How can I exit out safely once I find the desired results within the provided array? Is my condition faulty? Over complicating it? Because it just looks ridiculous to set answer = i so many times for no reason. Appreciate any input.

Comment: The issue here is that you are checking array[i] and comparing to array[j], rather than comparing it to the answer you already computed.  What you mean to do is compare the current value (array[i]) to the current answer, and then only reset the answer when it is smaller.

Note that you cannot set answer to 0 in that case, because 0 could be less than all the other numbers. So you could either set it to the first element in the list, or you could set it to the max integer.

Comment: Is Your input array sorted?

Comment: @slartidan no, its custom.

Comment: You can start by assigning first position as minimum. keep incrementing and checking for lesser number, if available replace minimum and keep checking till the end of input

Comment: @karan By first position, I believe you mean the first index? How would i be able to enter the loop then if the condition looks something like this: if(array[i] < min) i would not always be greater than the minimum index value, thus skipping the first iteration.

Comment: you already have minimum at index one, so your condition will fail. you don't need nested loops for this.

Comment: answer by green cloak guy does what I am saying.

Comment: @karan my mistake, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one layer to find the minimum, since you only need to keep track of the one variable:

```
public static int smallest(int[] array){
    int answer = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        // remove the inner for loop
        if (array[i] < answer) {
            answer = array[i];
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

What you do have, currently, is a very near implementation of selection sort:

```
public static void sort(int[] array){
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for(int j = i; j < array.length; j++){
            if(array[i] < array[j]){
                // replace the assignment to answer with a swap
                // to move the smaller element towards the front of the list
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you've figured out, about "it just looks ridiculous to set answer = i so many times" is essentially the difference between linear (`O(n)`) and quadratic (`O(n^2)`) complexity. For some things, like sorting, it's necessary to do more operations. Some things, like finding the minimum value, can be done with less effort.

Answer (score 2):

For this problem, a single loop will suffice.
Here are some pointers to help you out:

- Finding the smallest means you've directly or indirectly shown by comparison that some element is smaller than the other elements

  - Directly means you simply compared a < b
  - Indirectly means you showed that a < b and b < c, so a < c (transitivity)
- So if you compare the next element in the array with the smallest you have found so far, and do this until you have gone through the whole array, then you have the smallest element

Comment: Thanks, sometimes I need things like this spelled out for me.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want a full answer, here are some hints:

1. ```
   if(array[i] < array[j]){
       answer = i ;
   }
   ```

   If you think about this test, it's modifying `answer` based on the outcome of a test involving two items in the array, `array[i]` and `array[j]`. What if neither element is the smallest? The test doesn't check for that.

   You need to somehow involve `answer` in the test so you can keep track of the "smallest so far" as you loop over the array.
2. Finding the smallest number in a list doesn't need nested loops. If you did it on paper by hand you would be able to figure out the answer in a single pass, looking at each number just once. Your code should do the same thing: one loop, one pass.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to your nested for loop, you can use break;
But you can actually do this in one for loop:

```
int min = array[0];
for (int i = 1; i <array.length;i++) {
    min=Math.min(min,array[i]);
}
```

Math.min returns the lowest value between the two values put inside the parameters.

or you can do a for loop and compare elements at i and i+1!